# How to pass value from one form to another form in alfresco activiti workflow?

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I am facing problem in workflow.  The problem is : How to display the value entered by user1 to user2.  The scenario is as follows.  1. User1 starts a workflow -> form appears -> he enters a value in  textbox ->submit  2. user2 is reviewer gets the notification - > form appears -> display  the text entered by user1  Please guide me in whatever way it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In below code 
      **activiti:taskListener event="create"** 
This event will be executed with startEvent id="start" and userTask id="prepareTask" name="Prepare"  will  be populated values passed in  startEvent id="start" name="Start.

execution.setVariable('wf_sect', 'AAA');
                execution.setVariable('wf_dt', 'BBB');

```
 <userTask id="prepareTask" name="Prepare" activiti:candidateUsers="${candidatesPrepare}" activiti:formKey="wf:prepareTask">
          <documentation>
              "Prepare" task.
          </documentation>
          <extensionElements>
            <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
              <activiti:field name="script">
                <activiti:string>
            logger.log("PREPARE TASK!");
            task.setVariable('wf_sect', execution.getVariable('wf_sect'));
            logger.log("PREPARE TASK. TASK SECTION: " + task.getVariable('wf_sect'));
            task.setVariable('wf_dt', execution.getVariable('wf_dt'));
            logger.log("PREPARE TASK. TASK DT: " + task.getVariable('wf_dt'));
            </activiti:string>
              </activiti:field>
            </activiti:taskListener> 
            <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
              <activiti:field name="script">
                <activiti:string>
            logger.log("PREPARED (complete).");
            </activiti:string>
              </activiti:field>
            </activiti:taskListener>
          </extensionElements>
        </userTask>
```

Answer (score 1):

When designing your form for your second user you can select to include a field from a form previously completed by another user. The images below show a simple example of this:

First create a form and then add a display value/text field. From the dropdown you can select a field from another form, the one completed by your first user. Now when your second user views the task they will see the value entered by the first user.

[image: Display field]
[image: Selecting a form field value]
[image: First form]
[image: Second form]